# Cannot Use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: java, android

I have an alarm project, on `AlarmReceiver` I have this code.

the error is the flag is cannot be used, Android Studio say FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is not listed in usable Intent Flag.

how to fix that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbpLs.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, DoSomething.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Then in your `PendingIntent`

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the flag in the wrong place. Where you put it only flags for PendingIntent creation go.

You need to do this instead:

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Note (from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)): PendingIntent flags

> May be FLAG_ONE_SHOT, FLAG_NO_CREATE, FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, or any of the flags as supported by Intent.fillIn() to control which unspecified parts of the intent that can be supplied when the actual send happens.